# WCF client lifetime for autocomplete textbox

Tags: .net, winforms, wcf

I have winform app where i have autocomplete box filled from external web service. Its based on devexpress textedit which has nice feature to fire buffered onedit event (its not firing every time user enter character).
What is best practice when creating wcf channel, should i do it gracefully and for every onedit event (still about 1s period) create new channel and close it or its better to use one channel for whole session (form lifetime)?

Answer (score 0):

The **safest** thing to do is to re-create the channel for every call.

Why? Consider the scenario when you have a "long-lived" channel on the client.  If (for whatever reason) the channel faults, the channel is thenceforth unusable.  If you want to hit your service again you will have to write code that detects when the channel faults, tears it down and then recreates it.  You also need to remember to dispose of your channel before the application shuts down.  For me, the complexity that this introduces to your programming model is motivation enough to recreate the channel for every call.

Answers to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024278/wcf-createchannel-for-every-method-call) note that by holding the channel open you are holding resources on the client - far better to dispose of the resources as soon as they are no longer needed.  For a computer, 1 second is an age - you don't want to be holding resources for this time that you do not need.

However, you certainly want to be caching the `ChannelFactory` used to create the channel - but once you have this the creation of the underlying channel is cheap.